# GIMP only sometimes allows me to select areas to delete or change

Tags: gimp

I have Windows 8.1, and the 2.8.22 version of GIMP. I am currently trying to customize a chart for my paint colors. Sometimes GIMP works fine but much of the time when I select an area it won't allow me to do anything - not delete, not copy, not type into the selection. I need to know what I have to do to get GIMP to work all of the time. Please reply in simple terms, I'm a senior and tech talk isn't very easy for me to understand.
Thank you,]
Bernadine

Comment: I don't know what I do that makes the difference. Just after I wrote, I was able to cut and paste once and then it went back to before - not letting me cut and paste. I've spent hours just trying to get a simple chart changed and I'm very tired. Had the problem before, those times I just gave up. I've been trying to read the manual but most of it doesn't make sense, I can't even get GIMP to look like the examples. In a white square just below File, I did find another white square that says Clipboard right above it. When I right clicked on it, my selection that I want to move was there.

Comment: Replied but couldn't include you, so I'll post it here. Worked on this again for hours moved one item from its original place to another like I wanted. Think I selected the area, Layer>New from Visible, Select>Float, moved the dotted box to the new position, Layer>Anchor. might be able to do it again. Now want to delete the original area I moved, I don't want it there now. How do I do that? Nothing I've tried worked. Want to add some text to what I just moved and that's not working either. Also want to delete text that's just there, nothing to do with things I've already moved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Gimp lets you alter pixels that are, at the same time:

1. within the selection
2. within the boundaries of the current active layer/channel
3. not protected by the Color or Alpha locks

For each condition:

1. a minute selection can be overlooked. You can check if you have any selection by open the `Select` drop-down menu, if `Select>None` is not grayed, you have a selection somewhere.
2. the layer boundaries are shown with a dotted line (`View>Show layer boundaries`). 
   [image]
   If you need more space, you can use `Layer>Layer to image size` to extend the layer to completely cover the canvas. Also, make sure that you have a *layer* selected (blue highlight). Some operations select a *channel* and your alteration would apply to that instead.
3. The Color/Alpha locks are the two icons in the `Lock` line at the top of the Layers list.

[image]

In addition, many things are disabled when you have a "floating selection" (or only apply to it), and even more things are disabled in color-indexed images (as indicated by your title bar, typically when you are editing a GIF).

Two check lists:

https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-getting-unstuck.html#gimp-using-getting-unstuck

https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-When-suddenly-nothing-works-anymore

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't make any sense to me at all. !, In the Filters drop down menu, there is no Select>None or anything that says Select at all. 2. In View there is a Show layer boundaries, but nothing happened when I un-/re-checked it. 3. In the Layer menu there is nothing about Color or Alpha. I checked the 2 links. 1. I can't do this I have nothing like the first picture. 2. 4.1 I find nothing that looks like that picture. 4.2 Selection is checked. 4.3 Clicked on the Select all, tried copy/paste, nothing happened. 4.4 Nothing. Tired, making no sense. All I want to do is copy/paste.

Comment: `Filters`: Sorry I meant `Select`. Color/Alpha locks: see added screenshot. If your layer is a big as as the canvas, the dotted line for the layer boundary is on the sides of the canvas.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your Layers list and add it to your question? If you do `Select>All` and then Copy/Paste, you just duplicate the layer, so visually nothing changes, you just have one ore layer in the Layers list.

Comment: I tried to make a screenshot of my document but I don't know how to attach it here. And I don't know what the Layers list is.

Comment: I lost my comment I worked so hard on. I'll try again. I tried to make a screenshot but I don't know how to attach it. And I don't know what a Layers list it. With my document up, I did the Select>All and Ctrl C and Ctrl P here but nothing happened here. I do have the dotted line around the area I want to change like above. Some areas I want to delete and others I want to copy from one place to another on the same sheet. I did manage to delete one small area but I don't know what I did or how to do it again. I did find the lock like above but it has the whole sheet and nothing about layers.

Comment: Oh and I forgot, sometimes it will delete what I want to delete but then there's a checkerboard where the text had been and I don't want that, I want just the white of the sheet. I didn't have enough characters before to say thank you, so I add that also. Bernadine

Comment: The checkboard is just the bottom of the canvas. It is an **indication** of transparency. When you see it, it means that there are no opaque layers over that point. It is not really part of the picture.

Comment: Worked on this again for hours managed to move one symbol on the paper from its original place to another like I wanted. Think I selected the area, Layer>New from Visible, Select>Float, moved the dotted box to the new position, Layer>Anchor. I think I might be able to do it again. Now, I want to delete the original area that I wanted to move, I don't want it there now. How do I do that? Nothing I've tried worked. I want to add some text to what I just moved and that's not working either. Also want to delete text that's just there, nothing to do with things I've already moved. Thanks, Bernadine

Comment: Comments aren't a good place for more questions. Create a new question, but you may be more comfortable asking questions [there](https://www.gimp-forum.net/).

Comment: I don't know if I can start all over again. It took so much for me to write this all out and I'm still stuck with the original question, the others have just materialized as what I did to understand the first question caused more problems. Nothing worked when I tried to do what you wanted me to do, like making a screenshot or something about a layers list. And if too many people start answering, then I get even more confused especially when they contradict each other.

Comment: I went to the "there" page and wrote a question and some came up so I went to them and there were so many answers and I got to one that says simple and it didn't work. It's too much for me to sift through and try to understand. It used to work, just what I needed to do and now it won't.